# How to use Octave and Code::Block

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, octave

I'm trying to use Octave library with Code::Block on Win7 64bits, when I build code, I get lots of error message. The following is my step, any suggestions I am very appreciate.

1. Download and install octave-4.2.1-w64
2. Download and install Mingw
3. Download and install Code::Block
4. Add "C:\MinGW\bin" and "C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\bin" to Win 7 Environment   Variable Path.
5. Set Code::Block compiler setting, Compiler Settings->Search Directoies->Compiler add "C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\include" and "C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\include\octave-4.2.1"
6. Set Code::Block compiler setting, Compiler Settings->Search Directoies->Linker add "C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\lib"
7. Set Code::Block compiler setting, Compiler Settings->Linker settings->Add all library files under "C:\Octave\Octave-4.2.1\lib"
8. Add `#include <octave/oct.h>`, and I get lots of error message, does anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXJxD.png)

Comment: You don't have to (and it won't work) download and install Mingw because the Octave installer already includes gcc, g++ and so on. This is because Octave enables you to also compile octave-forge packages from source on windoze. If you use "mkoctfile" from Code::Block the wrapper script takes care of headers and libraries

Comment: Thanks your reply Andy, and what can I do first? To remove Mingw? I really have no idea to solve this issue.

Comment: I would try to remove Mingw, then compile an example from the example directory from the commandline (I think there is a cmdline.bat or domething like that in the Octave folder after installation) and then try to build inside Codeblocks. I'm sure there is a possibility to use external build tools or to retrieve the cxxflags and ldflags from mkoctfile (same procedure as with pkg-config)

Comment: 1.Remove Mingw, OK, I have done. 2. Compile an example from the example directory from the commandline. Hmm... I use command line in windows (cmd.exe), The message is, D:\Project\Small_Tool\Test>gcc main.cpp -o main.exe
main.cpp:2:24: fatal error: octave/oct.h: No such file or directory
 #include <octave/oct.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.

Comment: I said using `mkoctfile` and if you use the right commandline `cmdshell.bat` (not the windows cmd.exe) the PATH is already set.

Comment: Hi, Andy, thanks your reply, i am very appreciate :-), i execute cmdshell.bat, follow this url, https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Getting-Started-with-Oct_002dFiles.html , succeed create a file called helloworld.oct. But I can not doing next step=> helloworld (1, 2, 3),  the bash show the error message is syntax error near unexpected token '1,2,3'

Comment: open GNU Octave GUI or CLI, navigate to your compile helloworld.oct and execute the helloworls call again

Comment: In GNU Octave GUI is correct, it shows >> helloworld (1,2,3)
Hello World has 3 input arguments and 0 output arguments.